# c++ templates, how to map template parameters to other template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

Can I somehow make a map of template parameters? let's say I have the following function:

```
template<typename T>
T SumCoefficients(const std::vector<T>& coeffs) {
  T sum = static_cast<T>(0);
  for(int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
    sum += SomeFunc<T>(i) * coeffs[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

// explicit instantiation

template double SumCoefficients(const std::vector<double>& coeffs);
template float SumCoefficients(const std::vector<float>& coeffs);
template Vector3d SumCoefficients(const std::vector<Vector3d >& coeffs);
```

now, let's say I don't want to call `SomeFunc<T>(i)` but instead, if T==float, I want to use `SomeFunc<float>`, if T==double I want to use `SomeFunc<double>`, but if T==Vector3d I don't want to use `SomeFunc<Vector3d>` but instead `SomeFunc<double>`

now of course I could explicitely implement `template <> Vector3d SumCoefficients(std::vector<Vector3d > coeffs) { ... }` and then make the explicit call to `SomeFunc<double>`, but I wonder if there is an elegant way that gives me the same result with only a single template implementation plus explicit instantiation.

Comment: Sounds like you want something like this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints

Comment: Not the answer, but those are *explicit* instantiations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constexpr if approach is fine, but I'd like to add another solution which I think is preferable, if you have many calls to `SomeFunc` across your code base.

Another advantage of my solution is that it scales better if you have many types or you need to be able to add types later because the mapping logic is encapsulated in the template specialisations rather in the calling code.

I assume, what you want semantically is something like the scalar type of `T`:

```
template<typename T>
struct scalar_type {

    using type = T;
};

template<typename T>
using scalar_t = typename scalar_type<T>::type;
```

Now you can add sepcializations of this template for all types of vectors or matrices or whatever you need.

```
template<>
struct scalar_type<Vector3d> {

    using type = double;
};
```

Your calling code would look like this:

```
template<typename T>
auto SumCoefficients(const std::vector<T>& coeffs) {
  scalar_t<T> sum;
  for(int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
    sum += SomeFunc<scalar_t<T>>(i) * coeffs[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

If you're restricted to c++11, the call site could look like this:

```
template<typename T, typename Scalar = scalar_t<T>>
Scalar SumCoefficients(const std::vector<T>& coeffs) {
  Scalar sum;
  for(int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
    sum += SomeFunc<Scalar>(i) * coeffs[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

See full example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/1s6TjG)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) (since C++17) to check the type. e.g.

```
template<typename T>
T SumCoefficients(const std::vector<T>& coeffs) {
  T sum = static_cast<T>(0);
  for(int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Vector3d>) // when T is Vector3d
      sum += SomeFunc<double>(i) * coeffs[i];
    else
      sum += SomeFunc<T>(i) * coeffs[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: oh this looks like exactly what I want, thank you! I'll wait a bit until I accept the answer to see if there are other solutions, but this does already what I need, appreciated!

Comment: is there maybe a c++11 solution too?

Comment: @user1282931 Then as you said, you can full specialize `SumCoefficients` and call `SomeFunc<double>(i)` in it, (and might extract common processing to a common function and call it from `SumCoefficients`.) BTW: If `SomeFunc<Vector3d>(i)` is well-formed, you just don't want to call it, you can just use normal `if`, as `if (std::is_same_v<T, Vector3d>) sum += SomeFunc<double>(i) * coeffs[i]; else ...`.

Comment: SomeFunc<Vector3d>(i) is well-formed. would this result in a dynamic branch then or will the compiler generate the same code as with if constexpr?

Comment: @user1282931 I think it's not guaranteed like constexpr if, which guarantees the unnecessary statement would be discarded at compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

You asked for a C++11 solution, which can't use `if constexpr`:

```cpp
template<typename T>
T SumCoefficients(const std::vector<T>& coeffs) {
  using TTag = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, Vector3d>::value, double, T>::type;
  TTag sum = static_cast<TTag>(0);
  for(int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
    sum += SomeFunc<TTag>(i) * coeffs[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

(I made some assumptions on return type of `SomeFunc` and maybe something else, as your question didn't have full details, but I hope this will work for you)